# urldate not working

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, urls

I need to display the date of access for the websites cited in my dissertation. I've used `urldate = {}` , but it does not actually display any date. I only get the date printed when I use `date = {}`.

You can see my MWE below. The first bib entry has `urldate = {}`. The second entry with the key janzvat49 has the `date = {}`.

So,

- Why is urldate not working
- How do I get it to say Accessed on <*date*>.

  - It needs to come after the title and before the url preceded and followed by commas.
  - And for the bibliography, same place but preceded and followed by periods.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=12pt,headsep=12pt,ignorehead,ignorefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[series={A,B},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}



\usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption}
%\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,belowskip=-13pt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\SetLanguageKeys{english}{indentfirst=true}
\usepackage[style=sbl,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=100,minnames=1,backend=biber,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter,doi=false,url=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}



\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{SBL BibLit}[
Script=Greek,
Scale=MatchUppercase,
Ligatures=TeX
]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{SBL BibLit}[
Script=Hebrew,
Contextuals=Alternate,
Ligatures=Required
]

\begin{filecontents}{web.bib}
@online{janzvat,
  author= {Janz, Timothy},
  title = {Greek Paleography: From Antiquity to the Renaissance: 2. Introduction to Minuscule Bookhands},
  url = {https://spotlight.vatlib.it/greek-paleography/feature/2-introduction-to-minuscule-bookhands},
  urldate = {2022-02-11}
  }
  
@online{janzvat49,
author={Janz, Timothy},
title={Greek Paleography: From Antiquity to the Renaissance: 4. Ninth- and Tenth-Century Minuscules},
url={https://spotlight.vatlib.it/greek-paleography/feature/4-ninth-and-tenth-century-minuscules},
date = {2022-02-11}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{web.bib}

\begin{document}
Text\autocite{janzvat}. And two.\autocite{janzvat49}

\printbibliography[title=\normalfont BIBLIOGRAPHY]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`biblatex-sbl` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-sbl/biblatex-sbl.pdf)

> The SBLHS discourages the use of access dates. [See SBLHS §6.1.6, 84.]

so `urldate` is not shown by default, but you can use the option

```
accessdate
```

to get `urldate` printed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\SetLanguageKeys{english}{indentfirst=true}
\usepackage[style=sbl, accessdate]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{janzvat,
  author  = {Janz, Timothy},
  title   = {Greek Paleography: From Antiquity to the Renaissance: 2. Introduction to Minuscule Bookhands},
  url     = {https://spotlight.vatlib.it/greek-paleography/feature/2-introduction-to-minuscule-bookhands},
  urldate = {2022-02-11}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Text\autocite{janzvat}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Janz, Timothy. “Greek Paleography: From Antiquity to the Renaissance: 2. Introduction to Minuscule Bookhands.” Accessed 11 February 2022. https://spotlight.vatlib.it/greek-paleography/feature/2-introduction-to-minuscule-bookhands.]

Comment: thank you that does what I need. Just as a follow up, how can I change the order of the output date, instead of 11 February... to February 11?

Comment: I have made a separate question about that follow up: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667196/american-date-format