# American date format

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-sbl

I'm trying to get the American date format: "month day, year". Eg. "February 11, 2022". Based on the discussion here [Localized date with biblatex and polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464281/localized-date-with-biblatex-and-polyglossia) I was using `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{british}`. But all it does is change "Accessed" to "Visited".

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,openany,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.25in,right=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=12pt,headsep=12pt,ignorehead,ignorefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[series={A,B},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\linenumsep=-30pt plus 50pt minus 50pt
\ledlsnotesep=-100pt
\ledrsnotesep=-30pt


\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}


\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\SetLanguageKeys{english}{indentfirst=true}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{SBL BibLit}[
Script=Greek,
Scale=MatchUppercase,
Ligatures=TeX
]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{SBL BibLit}[
Script=Hebrew,
Contextuals=Alternate,
Ligatures=Required
]
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\setDefaultTransitions{\greekfont}{\rmfamily}
\setDefaultTransitions{\rmfamily}{\greekfont}

\usepackage[style=sbl,maxcitenames=3,maxbibnames=100,minnames=1,backend=biber,citepages=omit,fullbibrefs=true,sblfootnotes=false,citereset=chapter,doi=false,urldate=long,url=true,accessdate]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{web.bib}

@online{janzvat,
  author= {Janz, Timothy},
  title = {Greek Paleography: From Antiquity to the Renaissance: 2. Introduction to Minuscule Bookhands},
  url = {https://spotlight.vatlib.it/greek-paleography/feature/2-introduction-to-minuscule-bookhands},
  urldate = {2022-02-11}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{web.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american}

\begin{document}
Text.\autocite{janzvat}

\printbibliography[title=\normalfont BIBLIOGRAPHY]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex-sbl` explicitly redefines the "long" date format for `american` to "dd MMM yyyy". If you want to get back `biblatex`'s standard for American ("MMM dd, yyyy"), you can try the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\SetLanguageKeys{english}{indentfirst=true}
\usepackage[style=sbl, accessdate]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{american}{%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecomp{%
    \lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@long{long}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangeterse{%
    \lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@short{short}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangecompextra{%
    \lbx@us@mkdaterangetruncextra@long{long}}%
  \protected\def\mkdaterangeterseextra{%
    \lbx@us@mkdaterangetruncextra@short{short}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}
         {\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{,\space}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{janzvat,
  author  = {Janz, Timothy},
  title   = {Greek Paleography: From Antiquity to the Renaissance: 2. Introduction to Minuscule Bookhands},
  url     = {https://spotlight.vatlib.it/greek-paleography/feature/2-introduction-to-minuscule-bookhands},
  urldate = {2022-02-11}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Text\autocite{janzvat}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Janz, Timothy. “Greek Paleography: From Antiquity to the Renaissance: 2. Introduction to Minuscule Bookhands.” Accessed February 11, 2022. https://spotlight.vatlib.it/greek-paleography/feature/2-introduction-to-minuscule-bookhands.]